# CreateProcess with 2 redirected pipes return exitcode 1

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess

I'm new to WIN32 API and could use some help figuring what am I missing in my code.
My goal is to run a batch script (or PowerShell script), wait for completion, and then get the stdout / stderr upon completion.

Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) article on msdn about creating a process and redirecting stdout and stderr to a handle.
I *mashed* the samples together and came up with the following code:

```
int execute_commnad(std::string& command,std::string& output,int& timeout_seconds) {
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    DWORD return_code = NULL;

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    ZeroMemory(&si,sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.hStdOutput = child_stdout_handle;
    si.hStdError = child_stdout_handle;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Connect Child stdout to parent_stdout_handle
    if (!CreatePipe(&parent_stdout_handle,&child_stdout_handle,&saAttr,0))
    {
        output = "Could not create stdout pipe. Error: " + std::to_string(GetLastError());
        close_handles();
        return -1;
    }

    if (! SetHandleInformation(parent_stdout_handle,HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT,0))
    {
        output = "Could not set handle information for stdout pipe. Error: " + std::to_string(GetLastError());
        close_handles();
        return -1;
    }

    // Create Process
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,LPSTR(command.c_str()),NULL,NULL,TRUE,0,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi)) {
        output = "Failed to create process. Error: " + std::to_string(GetLastError());
        close_handles();
        return -1;
    }
    CloseHandle(child_stdout_handle);


    // Wait for process to finish or timeout
    if (timeout_seconds == NULL) {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
    }
    else {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,DWORD(timeout_seconds * 1000));
    }
    
    if (!GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess,&return_code)) {
        output = "Failed to fetch exit code";
        close_handles();
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (STILL_ACTIVE == return_code) {
        TerminateProcess(sub_process,return_code);
        output = "Command did not finish within defined timeout threshold";
    }
    else if (STATUS_PENDING == return_code) {
        output = "process is pending";
    }
    else {
        DWORD dwRead;
        CHAR chBuf[4096];
        BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

        for (;;) {
            bSuccess = ReadFile(parent_stdout_handle,chBuf,4096,&dwRead,NULL);
            if (! bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;
            output = *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(parent_stdout_handle);
        }
    }
    
    close_handles();
    return 0;    
};


void close_handles(void) {
    CloseHandle(parent_stdout_handle);
    CloseHandle(child_stdout_handle);
    CloseHandle(sub_process);
};
```

Before executing the function above I create the .bat file using `std::ofstream` containing "echo hello" and save the FQN of the file into variable named `file_name` and run the following code:

```
int rc = 0;
std::string cmd = "cmd.exe /c " + file_name + " " + script_params;
rc = execute_commnad(cmd,this->output,timeout_in_seconds);
```

When debugging these are the values I get after `GetExitCodeProcess`:

- cmd: cmd.exe /c "O:\\Programming\\cpp\...\\script_file.bat" 1 2 3
- return_code: 1

I have tried replacing `cmd.exe` with the FQN, but same result, tried running something as simple as `cmd.exe /c "echo hello"` and still returned return_code 1.

I've been struggling for the last 2 days in finding the reason for it, but to no avail.

Aside for the ineffective code (performance-wise) does anyone has a suggestion to what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to get the output of the child process instead of the return code? Then you should print the value of `chBuf` you read in `ReadFile`, and you need to set `si.hStdOutput/hStdError` after calling `CreatePipe`, otherwise the handle value is invalid.

Comment: FYI, `STILL_ACTIVE` is the WinAPI equivalent of NTAPI `STATUS_PENDING` in the context of the process exit status. In minwinbase.h, it's just a simple `#define STILL_ACTIVE STATUS_PENDING`. So checking for both is pointless.

Comment: It seems you should be appending the contents of `chBuf` to the `output` string in each pass after a successful `ReadFile` call. I can't fathom why you'd be doing the following: `output = *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(parent_stdout_handle)`.

Comment: You don't appear to actually set the global `sub_process` value to `pi.hProcess`. So you're leaking the `pi.hProcess` handle as well as `pi.hThread`, and `TerminateProcess` is being called on some random handle value. The usage of global variables is dubious here. You'd be better off without them.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT OMG that fixed the problem! so just to understand my error: I have linked the handles before they were "initialized" as pipe handles?

Comment: @ErykSun thank you for your feedback! I removed the `STATUS_PENDING` and replaced `*reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(parent_stdout_handle)` to `output = chBuf`. I removed `sub_process` because it is irrelevant - at first I thought I need a new handle to get  the exit-code, but I was wrong

Comment: Yes, if the initial value of `child_stdout_handle` is NULL, then `si.hStdOutput/hStdError = NULL` will be passed to `CreateProcess`

Comment: You can simplify your code if you remove explicit use of `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`. Pass the security attributes as `NULL`, which defaults to creating non-inheritable handles, and then manually make the child handle inheritable via `SetHandleInformation`, instead of vice versa. Also, there's no need to zero `pi` since a succesful `CreateProcess` call sets all fields, and `si` can be zeroed on the stack by the compiler via `STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(STARTUPINFO)}`.

Comment: Also, it's bad form to use `NULL` instead of 0 as an integer value in C (e.g. `DWORD return_code = NULL`). The `NULL` macro is a pointer (typically `(void *)0`) that implicitly converts to an integer. C++ code typically uses `nullptr` instead, which doesn't have that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to initialize the `child_stdout_handle` before passing the handle to `CreateProcess`.

In addition, you need to print the value of `chBuf` you read in `ReadFile`, instead of `parent_stdout_handle`. Converting file handle to `string` is meaningless, you could try:

```
    for (;;) {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(parent_stdout_handle, chBuf, 4096, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;
        chBuf[dwRead] = '\0';
        output += chBuf;
    }
    cout << output << endl;
```